# Data not updated on the remote machine after making git pull origin master, pipeline bitbucket

Tags: docker, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines, runner

I got this pipeline and a runner on my remote machine

bitbucket_pipeline.yml:

```
image: rust
pipelines:
   branches:
       master:
          - step:
              name: 'Staging'
              deployment: Staging
              runs-on:
                 - self.hosted
                 - linux
              script:
                 - cd /app
                 - pwd
                 - git init
                 - git remote add origin git@bitbucket.org:hha/app.git
                 - ls -la
                 - git fetch
                 - git checkout master
                 - git pull origin master
```

runner on the remote machine:

```
docker container run -it -v /app:/app -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v /var/lib/docker/containers:/var/lib/docker/containers:ro -e ACCOUNT_UUID={r3d4-ct3d} -e REPOSITORY_UUID={r3d4-ct3d} -e RUNNER_UUID={r3d4-ct3d} -e RUNTIME_PREREQUISITES_ENABLED=true -e OAUTH_CLIENT_ID=r3d4-ct3dyZ8wBSBh37CMWpGJLLJhofdbehlp -e OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET=WhhXu2eqwePNb9DF8VL_5R_s75HzqqQ1ugrakquRUmpPqft7vBpBfK0XBTrr3d4-ct3dBpBfK0XBTr -e WORKING_DIRECTORY=/app --name runner-r3d4-ct3d docker-public.packages.atlassian.com/sox/atlassian/bitbucket-pipelines-runner:1
```

Pipeline is working/passing after setting SSH keys pipeline, but I don't see any change on the path where the app is on my remote machine. Changes are done on the docker container but not on the path of my remote machine.

I have the volume on my runner -v /app:/app, but it seem doesn't work, why?. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You see, your container, which you have started on the self-hosted runner is not the actual runner container. For each task that container spawns a child container in which your code actually runs. And you, as far as I know, have no control over that container's configuration, so you can not mount a folder from your host to it.
The only way, to my knowledge, to run some arbitrary code on the host, where you run your self-hosted pipeline (or any other host) is to use ssh-run pipe, which actuall logs into your host by ssh and performs there the commands you need.
[Here](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/what-are-pipes/) is the explanation, what are bitbucket pipeline pipes and [here](https://bitbucket.org/product/features/pipelines/integrations) in the "Utilites" section you will find the documentation on ssh-run pipe.